# Gstreamer - vaapidecode with mpeg ts not playing

Tags: video, gstreamer

I'm trying to use gstreamer-vaapi plugins to play video in mpegts.

When using vaapi as suggested with

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=video.mp4 ! qtdemux ! vaapidecode ! vaapisink
```

and it is working, of course.

Also, TS playback works with

```
GST_DEBUG="*:3" gst-launch-0.10 -v udpsrc buffer-size="5000"   \
port=1234 multicast-group="239.0.0.17"   \
caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264"   \
! .recv_rtp_sink_0 gstrtpbin ! rtpmp2tdepay   \
! mpegtsdemux ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink
```

but when I want to replace `ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink` with `vaapidecode ! vaapisink` I get no video and [here](http://pastebin.com/rkmxF8yD) is log with `GST_DEBUG=*:3`.

I've found similar problem [here](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/gstreamer-vaapi-and-RTSP-tt3065372.html) and it is suggested to use `ffdemux_mpegts` instead of `tsdemux` because of sink caps that `vaapidecode` wants. Butit seams that `ffdemux_mpegts` is not any more in `gstreamer-ffmpeg` package as it had some problems before.

But anyways I don't see same error as [that guy](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/gstreamer-vaapi-and-RTSP-tt3065372.html).

Is there any way to discover what caps do `vaapidecode` needs and to add it manualy when demuxer can't do that?

Or it is some other problem?

Comment: cmd-line tools and related questions fit best at superuser.com

Comment: but this is related to programming as gst-launch is only test tool that makes easier to develop application

Comment: Independently of the reason you are using it, this is still a cmd-line tool and the question has very little programming content in it (I see a lot of command line arguments and parameters, and no code whatsoever). You will have more luck getting an answer on superuser.com , it's all I'm saying.

Comment: That bash code can be trivially translated into python code (`gst.parse_launch("filesrc location=video.mp4 ! qtdemux ! vaapidecode ! vaapisink")`), which apparently will magically turn the question into a programming question worthy of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this question is getting some attention lately, so here is what I know so far.

First of all, we need to move to Gstreamer 1.x, there are many things that are solved with newer version.

Another thing that I have on my mind is adding parser before decoder.

Also, there have been a patch for Gstreamer parser/decoder (don't remember) that fixes some problems with playing streamed h264 video.

I hope this will help you guys.